# Proving the Form of a Change of Basis Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $\mathcal{B}_1=\{\mathbf{v}_i\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_2=\{\mathbf{w}_i\}$ are bases. I'd like to prove that the matrix $T:V\to V$ whose columns are the components of $\{\mathbf{w}_k\}$ expressed in terms of $\mathcal{B}_1$ is the so called change of basis matrix from $\mathcal{B}_1$ to $\mathcal{B}_2$. Any ideas?

(Edit) Found this proof in Contemporary Linear Algebra by Anton and Busby:
Let $\mathcal{B}_1=\{\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_2=\{\mathbf{w}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{w}_n\}$ be bases for a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{w}_1&=a_{11}\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+a_{1n}\mathbf{v}_n\\
\mathbf{w}_2&=a_{21}\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+a_{2n}\mathbf{v}_n\\
&\vdots\\
\mathbf{w}_n&=a_{n1}\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+a_{nn}\mathbf{v}_n
\end{align*}

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be any element of $V$. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}&=k_1\mathbf{w}_1+\cdots+k_n\mathbf{w}_n\\
&=k_1(a_{11}\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+a_{1n}\mathbf{v}_n)+\cdots+k_n(a_{n1}\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+a_{nn}\mathbf{v}_n)\\
&=(k_1a_{11}+\cdots+k_n a_{n1})\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+(k_1a_{1n}+\cdots+k_n a_{nn})\mathbf{v}_n
\end{align*}
Thus, if $[\mathbf{x}]_{\mathcal{B}_1}$ and $[\mathbf{x}]_{\mathcal{B}_2}$ are the coordinate vectors of $\mathbf{x}$ w.r.t. each of the bases, we have
\begin{align*}
[\mathbf{x}]_{\mathcal{B}_1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{21}&\cdots&a_{n1}\\
a_{12}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{n2}\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
a_{1n}&a_{2n}&\cdots&a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
[\mathbf{x}]_{\mathcal{B}_2}
\end{align*}
Q.E.D.

Comment: This is the definition of the change of basis matrix. There's nothing to prove. Perhaps you wish to prove that if $\mathbf v$ is a vector in $V$ and $\mathbf x_1$ is its coordinate vector with respect to $\mathcal B_1$ and $\mathbf x_2$ is its coordinate vector with respect to $\mathcal B_2$, then $\mathbf x_1 = T\mathbf x_2$.

Comment: How do you mean? I've tried computing $T(\mathbf{v}_k)$ but I don't see why it must equal $\mathbf{w}_k$, and hence why it's the change of basis matrix.

Comment: But in terms of $\mathcal B_1$, the vector $\mathbf v_k$ is the $k$th standard basis vector. It doesn't matter what other coordinates you had for it. You might want to edit your post to include a concrete computational example, if that's what's causing you issues.

Comment: Ah, so it "extracts" the $k$-th column in a manner of speaking?

Comment: Precisely. Which is why I said this was all definition :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help dude

Comment: You're most welcome.

Comment: I found a proof of the result exactly the same as your suggestion, see above